# How do I enable the ability to move a frameless window in Electron and Svelte?

Tags: javascript, css, electron, svelte

I'm following [this article](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/how-to-make-your-first-desktop-app-with-electron-and-svelte-b1624e3edc54) to set up Electron and Svelte.

I wanted to make my window frameless so I enabled `frame: false` in `index.js` and it is successfully working and there is no title bar.

According to [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44823888/12868490), to enable moving, I need to use:

```css
.titlebar {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -webkit-app-region: drag;
}
```

But this doesn't work and I can't drag anything.
The entire Svelte code:

```html
<main>
   <h1>Hello</h1>
</main>
<style>
    main {
        --webkit-user-select: none;
        --webkit-app-region: drag;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 1em;
        max-width: 240px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    h1 {
        color: #ff3e00;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 4em;
        font-weight: 100;
    }

    @media (min-width: 640px) {
        main {
            max-width: none;
        }
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out I needed to add:

```css
* {
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -webkit-app-region: drag;
    }
```

to my Svelte app and then use `-webkit-app-region: no-drag !important;` for things that shouldn't be dragged like buttons.

Comment: I guess that once you have some UI such as a toolbar that is useful for dragging the entire window, then you'll be able to use something like `.titlebar` instead of `*` again, and will not need to use that `no-drag` on individual elements.